# AppiumDriver is unable to identify specific components/pageObjects ( button/image/label) on a android webView container

Tags: android, ios, automation, device, appium

I am using a hybrid application which is having a native and a webView context. Using **AppiumDriver**, it is seen that some of the components are not being identified on specific devices or system even though the actual xPath or name is not getting changed when inspected.

Appium app Version: 1.4.13
Appium node Version: 1.4.16

Example:

```
appiumDriver.findElementByName("Demo_Name").click(); // Working in device 1 but not on Device 2
```

or

```
 appiumDriver.findElementByName("//android.widget.Button[0][contains(@name,'Demo_Name')]").click(); // Working in device 2 but not on Device 1
```

And sometime nothings seems to be working. I did try **context switching** but still no luck.

Comment: did u try other identifiers such as id, contentdesc. if posible kindly add snip of element inspector

Comment: I hope the package installed on different devices is rendering same views to what you want to be able to access. What I mean here is, `.apk` builds could be designed to display different views categorising the `resolution` of the devices. In which case you need to be sure that you are viewing the same View on both the devices. Could you specify the **device details** to make the question more clear and snip of **Appium Inspector** would actually be great to see from both of them with the same view. This could very well be your app issue as well depending on the details you provide.

Comment: for your second query try using `appiumDriver.findElementByXpath("//android.widget.Button[0][contains(@name,'Demo_Name')]").click();` instead